# How to export a method in a functional typescript class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

In the code below I would like to know, how to export the function *setFormData*. In other words also I would like to know how to import *setFormData* from a different typescript file. Thank you

**File A**

```
import { SyntheticEvent } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useStatusActions } from '../../actions';

export const StatusHelper = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  let statusActions = useStatusActions(dispatch);

  const setFormData = (event: SyntheticEvent, key: any, value: any) => {
    statusActions.setFormData(key, value);
  };
```

File B

```
import {
  setFormData,
} from './fileA';
```

Answer (score 2):

you will need to create a custom hook if you want to export a function that relies on another hook. You can't simply export and use it outside react.

you should have a `useStatusHelper` hook that returns a `setFormData` function

check how to create custom hooks [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-custom.html)